# Wronskian and extremum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ , $p,q$ are continuous functions in $[a,b]$ and $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ are the solutions.

$a\leq x_0\leq b$

Prove\disprove:

1.If $y_1(x_0)=y_2(x_0)=0 \implies y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent.

2.If $y_1,y_2$ get an extremum in $x_0 \implies y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent.

3.If $y_1,y_2$ get an inflection point in $x_0$, and $\forall x\in [a,b]   q(x)\neq0 $or$ p(x)\neq0 $(or both)  $\implies y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent.

I'd be grateful for your feedback for 1,2 and some help for 3

**My solution :**

$1.W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x_{0})=\left|\begin{matrix}y_{1}(x_{0}) & y_{2}(x_{0})\\
y'_{1}(x_{0}) & y'_{2}(x_{0})
\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}0 & 0\\
y'_{1}(x_{0}) & y'_{2}(x_{0})
\end{matrix}\right|=\implies W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x_{0})=0$

$p,q$ are continuous functions, since the ode exists the Uniqueness and Existence theorem then $\forall x\in [a,b]$ exists $W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x)=0 \implies  y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent.

$2.W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x_{0})=\left|\begin{matrix}y_{1}(x_{0}) & y_{2}(x_{0})\\
y'_{1}(x_{0}) & y'_{2}(x_{0})
\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}y_{1}(x_{0}) & y_{2}(x_{0})\\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right|=\implies W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x_{0})=0$

$p,q$ are continuous functions, since the ode exists the Uniqueness and Existence theorem then $\forall x\in [a,b]$ exists $W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x)=0 \implies  y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent.

$3.W[y_{1,}y_{2}](x_{0})=\left|\begin{matrix}y_{1}(x_{0}) & y_{2}(x_{0})\\
y'_{1}(x_{0}) & y'_{2}(x_{0})
\end{matrix}\right|=y_1y'_2-y_2y'_1$

I tried to derivative this for getting $0$.

$(y_1y'_2-y_2y'_1)'=y'_1y'_2+y_1y''_2-y'_2y'_1-y_2y''_1=0$

I get stuck and I don't know how to solve $3$ and why the given $\forall x\in [a,b]   q(x)\neq0,p(x)\neq0$ are important.

Thank you !

Comment: Just insert $y_k''(x_0)=0$ into the original DE, this establishes a linear dependence in the Wronksian matrix.

Comment: @LutzLehmann But why the fact $∀x∈[a,b]q(x)≠0,p(x)≠0$ (at least one of them) is important ? cant get it

Comment: For a linear dependence you need at least one coefficient in the linear combination to be non-zero. (If only one coefficient is non-zero in a linear combination of the zero vector, then the corresponding vector after the coefficient is already zero.)